# How to get alert boxes and validation working on this code

Tags: javascript, html

I got this code made but i can't get it to validate the required fields with alert boxes for missing fields or submit to a pop up window like i'm trying to do. The code is supposed to validate certain fields that only show up when one of the radio buttons are clicked and a pop up window containing a url is supposed to show up after submission. Not working. Need help.

Code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('ifBusiness').style.display='none';
}

function BusinessorResidence() {
  if(document.getElementById('businessCheck').checked) {
    document.getElementById('ifBusiness').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('ifResidence').style.display='none';
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('ifBusiness').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('ifResidence').style.display='block';
  }
}

function validateForm() {
  var address=document.forms["myForm"]["address"];
  var bname=document.forms["myForm"]["bname"];
  var url=document.forms["myForm"]["url"];
  var id=document.forms["myForm"]["tax"];
  var rname=document.forms["myForm"]["rname"];
  var email=documen.forms["myForm"]["email"];

  if(address.value == "") {
    alert("Please enter an address.");
    address.focus;
    return false;
  }

  if(bname.value == "") {
    alert("Please enter a business name.");
    bname.focus;
    return false;
  }

  if(url.value == "") {
    alert("Please enter a business URL.");
    url.focus;
    return false;
  }

  if(id.value == "") {
    alert("Please enter a business tax ID.");
    id.focus;
    return false;
  }

  if(rname.value == "") {
    alert("Please enter a residence name.");
    rname.focus;
    return false;
  }

  if(email.value == "") {
    alert("Please enter an email address.");
    email.focus;
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Javascript Assignment</title>
    <center><h1>Fill the form below</h1>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="myForm" action="http://csit.selu.edu/cgi-bin/echo.cgi" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
      <center><p><b>Address: </b><input type="text" name="address"></p>
      <div>
      <div>
      <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:BusinessorResidence();" name="businessresidence" id="businessCheck">This is a Business <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:BusinessorResidence();" name="businessresidence" id="residenceChceck">This is a Residence<br>
      <div id="ifBusiness" style="display:none">
      <b>Business Name: </b><input type="text" id="name" name="bname"><br>
      <b>Business Website URL: </b><input type="text" id="url" name="url"><br>
      <b>Business Tax ID: </b><input type="text" id="tax" name="tax"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </div>
      <div id="ifResidence" style="display:none">
      <b>Name: </b><input type="text" id="name" name="rname"><br>
      <b>Email: </b><input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"></center>
      </div>
    </form>

    <hr>
    <hr>
    </body>
</html>
```

The alert boxes are not popping up and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: If you only need to  check the existence of a value ( so no empty strings ), you can add the 'required' attribute to all the `<input>` elements that cannot be empty. No javascript required. Or is the alert() and such part of the actual assignment?

Comment: The alert boxes are necessary and i do need to use validation for proper url and email, but i'll work on it after i figure this out.

Comment: Open your debugger. You have a basic typing error that's very obvious once you run the code. Fix it and the alerts work.

Comment: I ran this in notepad as an html file. Where do i find a debugger?

Comment: Press F12 in the browser. How do you know you have errors if you do not use the debugger? That's the first thing you learn when coding JS. PS: you still have logic issues as well. For example, when you select residence, you still get alerts that the business email cannot be empty. But you can fix those yourself.

Comment: I just hit submit with the fields empty in a browser and nothing happens. How do i go through the debugging process. I am not kidding, step by step please

Comment: Did you fix the typo? You have `var email=documen.forms["myForm"]["email"];` so `documen` instead of `document`. A simple typing error. I copy pasted your code into notepad, opened the console with F12 and that was the first and only thing the browser complained about. So fix the typo and try again.

Comment: Go to notepad. Press run. Press 'Launch in Chrome' ( or other browser ) . The page should now open in the browser. Then press F12. A popup should appear with a bunch of tabs, one of the tabs should be 'console'. Press the console tab. All your errors will appear here. You should always have the console open when fixing issues with code, since it tells you what's wrong and on which line of your code.

Comment: ok fixed new problem. The required fields under residence are also being flagged when it is not clicked and the alert boxes show up. Any tips on how to fix that please?

Comment: Simple if statement?

Comment: elaborate on the if statement please. I'm having trouble here.

Comment: If the businessCheck radio is checked, you want to validate bname, tax and url. If not, you want to validate rname and email.

Comment: I get that, but where would it go in the code exactly? I'm sorry for all the questions but i will probably mess this up if I guess.

Comment: Also, how to make the submit button submit to a pop-up window that contains this url: www.selu.edu

Comment: 1) Inside validateForm(), wrap the respective if-clauses inside another if checking the radio button. 2) And I don't understand what `a pop up window containing a url is supposed to show up after submission` means. That's not possible. You can show an alert() Before the submit happens. But after the submit, the page is gone, so no pop ups can be shown. The response to the submit though works for me as well. So when I submit the form, I get back this html table on screen.

Comment: This is what i meant: If no errors exist, then the form should submit to http://csit.selu.edu/cgi-bin/echo.cgi and a pop-up window 
should come up (and in the foreground) populated with the URL www.selu.edu and dimensions 400x400 
and no menu bar, no status bar, and no scroll bars.

Comment: BTW, I'm sorry if i sound stupid but how would the if-clauses look in the code?

Comment: Is the 400 by 400 and such required? Since  now we get into more complicated territory. Normally you can use the `target="_blank"` attribute on the form tag to open the result in a different 'popup'. But if you have to remove bars and such, we'd have to open the window first, before submitting.

Comment: I think it is required but how would I make the submit button create the pop-up window in the code?

Comment: Is this homework or something? I do not understand why you have a non-trivial assignment like this when you doubt how to write if-clauses. Anyways, to set the popup dimensions to 400 and such, you have to use the correct window.open() parameters to set 400*400 and no scroll bars and such, and then use that window as the target of the form, Before submitting. Do you understand any of that?

Comment: I kind of do but i don't know where to place something like that in my code. And it is kinda homework but i still need to figure this out for myself since i mostly figured this out.

Comment: will this work for submission:
function myFunction() {
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
var w = window.open('about:blank','Popup_Window','toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusb
ar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=400,height=400,left = 312,top = 234');
myForm.target = 'Popup_Window';
return true;
}
Added onclick myFunction to my submit input type tag

Comment: Still writing, give me a few minutes.

Comment: Sorry just brainstorming

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, I have added the if-clause checking for business or not.

I also added the code to open the form submission into a new window.

Finally I cleaned up all the things you should not use anymore, like obsolete HTML tags like `<b>` and `<center>` and such, adding comments when appropriate.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      <h1>Javascript Assignment</h1>
      <!-- the titles should be inside the title, not inside the <head> tag -->
      <h2>Fill the form below</h2>
    </title>
    <!-- center tag is deprecated and should be replaced by CSS -->
    <style>
    head {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .bold {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    </style>
    <!-- script tags should be at the bottom of the body, not inside the <head> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="myForm" action="http://csit.selu.edu/cgi-bin/echo.cgi" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
      <p>
        <span class="bold">Address: </span>
        <input type="text" name="address">
      </p>
      <div>
        <div>
          <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:BusinessorResidence();" name="businessresidence" id="businessCheck">This is a Business
          <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:BusinessorResidence();" name="businessresidence" id="residenceChceck">This is a Residence
          <br>
          <div id="ifBusiness" style="display:none">
            <!-- <b> tag is deprecated. should be done with CSS -->
            <span class="bold">Business Name:</span>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="bname">
            <br>
            <span class="bold">Business Website URL:</span>
            <input type="text" id="url" name="url">
            <br>
            <span class="bold">Business Tax ID: </span>
            <input type="text" id="tax" name="tax">
          </div>
          <div id="ifResidence" style="display:none">
            <span class="bold">Name: </span>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="rname">
            <br>
            <span class="bold">Email: </span>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
          </div>
        <!-- missed the closing </div> -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Only one submit button per form -->
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <!-- script tags should be at the bottom of the body, not inside the <head> -->
    <!-- both scripts can be in the same <script> tag -->
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById('ifBusiness').style.display='none';
    }

    function BusinessorResidence() {
      var is_business = document.getElementById('businessCheck').checked;
      if ( is_business ) {
        document.getElementById('ifBusiness').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('ifResidence').style.display='none';
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById('ifBusiness').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('ifResidence').style.display='block';
      }
    }

    function validateForm() {
      var is_business = document.getElementById('businessCheck').checked;
      var address = document.forms["myForm"]["address"];
      var bname = document.forms["myForm"]["bname"];
      var url = document.forms["myForm"]["url"];
      var tax = document.forms["myForm"]["tax"];
      var rname = document.forms["myForm"]["rname"];
      var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"];
      // Address always has to be checked
      if ( address.value == "" ) {
        alert("Please enter an address.");
        address.focus();
        return false;
      }
      // Check the banem, tax and url if a business is selected
      if ( is_business ) {
        if ( bname.value == "" ) {
          alert("Please enter a business name.");
          // focus() is a method, not a property, so you need to call this function to actually focus the text input.
          bname.focus();
          return false;
        }
        // It does not make sense to call the tax id "id", tax is a better name.
        if ( tax.value == "" ) {
          alert("Please enter a business tax ID.");
          tax.focus();
          return false;
        }
        if ( url.value == "" ) {
          alert("Please enter a business URL.");
          url.focus();
          return false;
        }
      }
      // Else check the rname and the email
      else {
        if ( rname.value == "" ) {
          alert("Please enter a residence name.");
          rname.focus();
          return false;
        }
        if ( email.value == "" ) {
          alert("Please enter an email address.");
          email.focus();
          return false;
        }
      }
      // Open the popup window.
      // _blank refers to it being a new window
      // SELU is the name we'll use for the window.
      // The last string is the options we need.
      var popup = window.open( '', 'SELU', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=400,height=400,left=312,top=234' );
      // Set the form target to the name of the newly created popup.
      var form = document.querySelector( 'form[name="myForm"]' );
      form.setAttribute( 'target', 'SELU' );
      // Continue as normal
      return true;
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks man really but one last thing, I can figure it out myself maybe but i want to do this right. What would be good regular expressions for inputting proper email and url inputs.

Comment: That's a more difficult one. Just type it in in google and pick the ones you like. The naive way is just checking for 'anything @ anything . anything'. And for urls 'anything :// '. I say 'pick the one you like' because there's several versions. ( eg, `[\w-]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+` ) Unicode or not? Foreign languages? Same for urls, since something like `sphere://myserver/` can be a valid internal url, but probably isn't a valid public url.

Comment: it doesn't need to be complex , just needs to be like this:
Email: [alphanumeric string including . and _ ]@ [alphanumeric string including . and _ ]. [alpha 
string] 

Website: www.[alphanumeric string including . _ -].[com or net or org or edu]

Comment: Where would I put the email and url expressions in the code, I'm sorry but this is pretty much all that is left

Comment: Either in a seperate function: `if ( is_valid_email( email.value )) { ... }`, or directly inside the if clause: `if ( /someRegExp/.test( email.value )) { ... }`.